# Stop multiple ggplot sharing the same scale_colour_manual?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have multiple ggplots to store in a list. However, they may have different colorscales I want to use. The example is shown below in section 1 and 2. Each one generates the plot perfectly by itself. But if I combine the two, as the second one has fewer color scale(1) than the first one (3), an error will be returned when printing the first one afterward.(Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 1 provided.) Not sure if this is because of the earlier version of ggplot (2.1.0). Appreciate any idea to solve such problem.

```
data1<-mtcars;
data1$cyl<-as.factor(data1$cyl);
#section 1 #
plotlist[[1]]<-ggplot(data1[],aes_string(x='hp',y='wt',group=paste('paste0(','gear',',','cyl',')'),fill=('cyl')))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position="dodge",size=1);
colourCount <- 3;
getPalette <- colorRampPalette(c(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")[c(1:3,8:11)]));

plotlist[[1]]<-plotlist[[1]]+scale_colour_manual(values = rep(getPalette(min(colourCount,25)),times=floor(colourCount/25)+1))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep(getPalette(min(colourCount,25)),times=floor(colourCount/25)+1));#adjust color

#section 2 #
plotlist[[2]]<-ggplot(data1[data1$cyl==4,],aes_string(x='hp',y='wt',group=paste('paste0(','gear',',','cyl',')'),fill=('cyl')))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position="dodge",size=1);

colourCount <- 1;
getPalette <- colorRampPalette(c(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")[c(1:3,8:11)]));
plotlist[[2]]<-plotlist[[2]]+scale_colour_manual(values = rep(getPalette(min(colourCount,25)),times=floor(colourCount/25)+1))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep(getPalette(min(colourCount,25)),times=floor(colourCount/25)+1));
```

Comment: This is R, not JavaScript. Semicolons? Srsly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same variable for `colourCount` for both graph. So when you call the first plot, after affecting 1 to `colourCount`, the number of values is wrong(1 instead of 3)

if you change to

```
colourCount <- list()
colourCount[[1]] <- 3;
...
colourCount[[2]] <- 1;
```

and use the corresponding variable name in each plot it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @timat. It does work in this simple case. however, it does not work for me when it becomes a loop (in which I still define colourCount[[ii]]). Not sure what's causing the problem. But I found the workaround is that after the object is created within each loop, call ggplot_build(plotlist[[ii]]).  it seems such error will go away.But again, thank you so much.

Comment: you're welcome. If it works in this cases, can you mark as resolved ? (click the grey check under the downvote arrow. thanks